# No File Extension

Tags: php, android, file-extension

I am using my android app to upload some files on my wamp server. The files are successfully uploaded on the server, but there is no extension to the files, who have [Space] in the file name. Every time I try to open these files, the system prompts me to choose an application to open with. If I choose the relevant application, the file opens successfully. 
Is there any way to make these extensions available, so that I don't have to select the an application each time?

My PHP code is:

```
$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
} ?>
```

'

Comment: Are you saying that if a file contains a space, "and" it has a file extension for the original, that the uploaded file will no longer have an extension if the file contains a space?

Comment: Yes, for e.g. if the original file name on the phone is "abc xyz.pdf", the uploaded file name on server will be just "abc". Nothing else.

Comment: You can use `str_replace()` to replace the space(s) with an underscore. That's what I had to do for someone before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my java code to the following:

**Previous Code**

`dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name= \"uploaded_file\";filename="+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);`

**Updated Code**

`dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name= \"uploaded_file\";filename="+ fileName.replace(" ", "_") + "" + lineEnd);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()` to replace the spaces with an underscore:

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
```

or using `preg_replace()`

```
$file_path = "uploads";
$file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$newfilename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $file);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path. "/" .$newfilename))
```

Comment: I tried this `$fileName = str_replace(" ","_", basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']));` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @PrerakSola Ok, reload the answer again and give that a try.

Comment: `basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);` is returning just "abc" from "abc xyz.pdf".
So I think, my java code is sending the file with half name.

Comment: @PrerakSola ah ok. Could very well be the java, and that's something I don't know anything about, sorry.

Comment: I used the same logic on java side. I just renamed the file while sending it. You can see my answer.

Comment: @PrerakSola You're welcome. Thanks for the update with the answer you posted, it's a good addition :) *Cheers* and I upvoted it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_path = "uploads/";
$fine_name=basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).'.'."txt";//<put extention here like     txt,apk,htm,mp3 etc>

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path."/".$fine_name)) {
echo "success";
} else{
echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: User can select any type of file. So I don't know, what the extension would be.

Comment: move_uploaded_file() are work well
if you feel some Error

then you can USE copy() method

// For check Extention of file USE

$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

for more detail you can see
var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_file']);// you will understand